# How to use the minecraft 1.9 "Passengers" tag?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was wondering how to use the new 1.9 stacking tag, which i believe goes like this:

```
/summon Chicken ~ ~ ~ {Passengers:[{id:"Slime"­}]}`
```

I am wondering how to use this to give players colored leather armor that's "riding" each other, so that pushing on button gives a player a full set of colored armor.
Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: You use it like the `Riding:` tag, only with the mob stack defined from the bottom-up as opposed to top-down.

Comment: You can't use `Passengers` for equipping armor, because armor is defined by slots in the inventory, not a bunch of entities riding each other. Im not sure, whether you can stack items this way, to just give the player multiple items.

Comment: I was under the impression that questions concerning unreleased versions of game was not allowed as the question and any answers become quickly and easily invalid as such question may refer to feature that can and most likely will either change or even be removed.

Answer (score 9):

Since `Passengers` is a list, you separate each rider (the slime) of the root entity (the chicken) with a comma. This differs from `Riding` in that each rider is not required to ride one another, though it is still possible by including `Passengers` with each rider.

The following would summon a pair of leather boots as the root entity, that had 3 other riders at the same depth:

```
/summon Item ~ ~1 ~ {Item:{id:"minecraft:leather_boots",Count:1},Passengers:[{id:"Item",Item:{id:"minecraft:leather_leggings",Count:1}},{id:"Item",Item:{id:"minecraft:leather_chestplate",Count:1}},{id:"Item",Item:{id:"minecraft:leather_helmet",Count:1}}]}
```

If you want them nested further, similar to a `Riding` stack, you'll have to add `Passengers` to the rider:

```
/summon Item ~ ~1 ~ {Item:{id:"minecraft:leather_boots",Count:1},Passengers:[{id:"Item",Item:{id:"minecraft:leather_leggings",Count:1},Passengers:[{id:"Item",Item:{id:"minecraft:leather_chestplate",Count:1},Passengers:[{id:"Item",Item:{id:"minecraft:leather_helmet",Count:1}}]}]}]}
```

Comment: Dang. You beaten me.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use [McStacker](http://mcstacker.bimbimma.com/) selecting as Minecraft version 1.9 Snapshots

[image: McStacker Image]